# Rspec2, Rails3, Authlogic: Can't run specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

When I do

```
rspec spec
```

in my rails project, I get

```
No examples were matched. Perhaps {:if=>#<Proc:0x0000010126e998@/Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:50 (lambda)>, :unless=>#<Proc:0x0000010126e970@/Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:51 (lambda)>} is excluding everything?


Finished in 0.00004 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Now, this seems like maybe if I wrote a spec it would work, but as soon as I write a spec (and I do include spec_helper)

```
/Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Authlogic (NameError)
    from /{myapp}/app/models/user_session.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /{myapp}/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /{myapp}/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /{myapp}/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `load'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `map'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

The important line here seems to be

```
/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Authlogic (NameError)
```

Now if this were rails 2.3.8, I'd simply put
config.gem "authlogic"

into the environment.rb, in the initialization code block. However, the rails 3 environment.rb looks way different (there is no config code block, so putting it in arbitrarily causes an error where config is not defined). So my questions are

1) Do I actually have to put the gem config anywhere? I looked at https://github.com/trevmex/authlogic_rails3_example/ and it seems he didn't put it anywhere.

2) Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in terms of rspec? My gem list is

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.4)
actionpack (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.4)
activemodel (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2)
activerecord (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.4)
activeresource (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.4)
activesupport (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.4)
arel (2.0.6, 1.0.1)
asdf (0.5.0)
authlogic (2.1.6, 2.1.3)
autotest (4.4.6, 4.4.1)
autotest-fsevent (0.2.4)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
autotest-rails (4.1.0)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
bluecloth (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7, 1.0.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
commonwatir (1.6.2)
couchrest (0.33)
cri (1.0.1)
cucumber (0.4.4, 0.4.3, 0.3.11)
daemons (1.1.0, 1.0.10)
dependencies (0.0.7)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastercsv (1.5.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
firewatir (1.6.2)
flay (1.4.0)
flog (2.2.0)
funfx (0.2.2)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gemsonrails (0.7.2)
giraffesoft-resource_controller (0.6.5)
haml (2.2.14)
hoe (2.3.3)
i18n (0.4.1)
jscruggs-metric_fu (1.1.5)
json_pure (1.1.9)
kramdown (0.12.0)
mail (2.2.13, 2.2.6.1)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
mime-types (1.16)
mojombo-chronic (0.3.0)
mongrel (1.1.5)
monk (0.0.7)
nanoc (3.1.5)
nanoc3 (3.1.5)
nokogiri (1.4.3.1, 1.4.0)
open4 (0.9.6)
polyglot (0.3.1, 0.2.9)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.0, 2.3.4)
rails3-generators (0.17.0, 0.14.0)
railties (3.0.3, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc2)
rake (0.8.7)
relevance-rcov (0.9.2.1)
rest-client (1.0.3)
rspec (2.3.0, 2.0.0.rc, 1.2.9)
rspec-core (2.3.1, 2.0.0.rc)
rspec-expectations (2.3.0, 2.0.0.rc)
rspec-mocks (2.3.0, 2.0.0.rc)
rspec-rails (2.3.1, 2.0.0.rc, 1.2.9)
ruby_parser (2.0.4)
rubyforge (2.0.3)
rubygems-update (1.3.6, 1.3.5)
rvm (1.0.13)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
safariwatir (0.3.7)
sexp_processor (3.0.3)
spork (0.7.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1, 1.2.5)
sys-uname (0.8.5)
term-ansicolor (1.0.4)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.14.6, 0.14.3, 0.12.0)
treetop (1.4.8, 1.4.2)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
user-choices (1.1.6)
vlad (2.0.0)
vlad-git (2.1.0)
webrat (0.7.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.3)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
ZenTest (4.4.2)
```

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3 installed using RVM on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard.

I just want to be able to run my specs like I used to. As a separate issue, autotest yields an error about an include for autotest/growl but I installed autotest-growl. Maybe this is a gem issue? I tried doing the same things and get the same error when it comes to using my ubuntu 10.04 server machine though.

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :couch do
    gem 'couchrest'
end

group :user_auth do
  gem 'authlogic'
  gem "rails3-generators"
  gem 'facebooker'
end

group :markup do
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'sass'
end

group :testing do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'autotest'
end

group :server do
  gem 'unicorn'
end
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ZenTest (4.4.2)
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.2.9)
    actionpack (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.13)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.6)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    activerecord (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
    activesupport (3.0.3)
    arel (2.0.6)
    authlogic (2.1.6)
      activesupport
    autotest (4.4.6)
      ZenTest (>= 4.4.1)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (0.4.0)
      celerity (>= 0.7.9)
      culerity (>= 0.2.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0.0.27)
      xpath (~> 0.1.2)
    celerity (0.8.6)
    childprocess (0.1.6)
      ffi (~> 0.6.3)
    couchrest (1.0.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      mime-types (>= 1.15)
      rest-client (>= 1.5.1)
    cucumber (0.10.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.3.2)
      json (~> 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    culerity (0.2.13)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    facebooker (1.0.75)
      json_pure (>= 1.0.0)
    factory_girl (1.3.2)
    ffi (0.6.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    gherkin (2.3.2)
      json (~> 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    haml (3.0.25)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    json (1.4.6)
    json_pure (1.4.6)
    kgio (2.0.0)
    mail (2.2.13)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.4)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.1)
    rack-mount (0.6.13)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      activerecord (= 3.0.3)
      activeresource (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.3)
    rails3-generators (0.17.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rest-client (1.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.3.0)
    rspec-core (2.3.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.3.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.3.0)
    rspec-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.3.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.0.alpha.206)
    selenium-webdriver (0.1.2)
      childprocess (~> 0.1.5)
      ffi (~> 0.6.3)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    shoulda (2.11.3)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.23)
    unicorn (3.1.0)
      kgio (~> 2.0.0)
      rack
    webrat (0.7.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    xpath (0.1.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authlogic
  autotest
  capybara
  couchrest
  cucumber
  facebooker
  factory_girl
  haml
  rails (= 3.0.3)
  rails3-generators
  rspec
  rspec-rails
  sass
  shoulda
  sqlite3-ruby
  unicorn
  webrat
```

Comment: which gem: /Users/samliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/gem
which ruby: /Users/samliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
which rails: /Users/samliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/bin/rails

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your issue, but the official Authlogic gem does not support Rails 3. Use this in your Gemfile instead: `gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'`

Comment: Have you tried changing environment from `testing` to `test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Not entirely sure what the issue was, but I uninstalled rubygems and ruby from the system and reinstalled only using rvm -- then I went with devise over authlogic. Seems that for some reason authlogic just wasn't playing nice with me. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

All you config.gem are now in your Gemfile. So put it on :

```
gem 'authologic'
```

Comment: Hi shingara, yes it's already there for me. but even after bundle install, bundle update, whatever it's still giving me the above error.

Comment: can you paste your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock please ?

Comment: posted. another interesting thing I've realized...I installed a gem on my osx machine called prologue. I did the same on my ubuntu -- and on ubuntu, "prologue" is a command I can use. on osx, it is not the case. I think this might be a case of a system problem...